# No matching files during upload junit artifacts

Tags: junit, pytest, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I'm struggling with getting junit artifacts (junit.xml file) after testrun job with pytest on Gitlab. The job runs in k8s pod and looks like this:

```
testrun:component:
  image: ...
  tags:
    - ...
  stage: testrun
  script:
    - <some previous setup steps>
    - >
      helm install "some namespace"
      -- set ...
      ...
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: ./test_results/junit.xml
    expire_in: 1 week
```

Pod log contains string: `generated xml file: /main/test_results/junit.xml`. When I go inside the pod I see folder `test_results` with junit.xml inside. It even being copied to S3 from the bash script what launches pytest. But finally path `./test_results/junit.xml` is incorrect and I get the error

```
WARNING: ./test_results/junit.xml: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload
```

The CI job debug log near upload action contains this:

```
++ cd /builds/<some_folder>/main
++ /usr/bin/gitlab-runner-helper --version
Uploading artifacts...
++ echo 'Uploading artifacts...'
++ /usr/bin/gitlab-runner-helper artifacts-uploader --url https://<example.com>/ --token [MASKED] --id 123456 --path ./test_results/junit.xml --name junit.xml --expire-in '1 week' --artifact-format gzip --artifact-type junit
WARNING: ./test_results/junit.xml: no matching files
```

I'm curious where could be the problem?

Comment: Does mounting a volume on a pod that runs the test help?

Comment: I suspect the situation is more complex with my case than I thought before. I see the error in job logs while it is still working and junit.xml file isn't generated yet.

Comment: Now I see the situation as a Gitlab CI job which has `helm install`, looks completed after helm call but a namespace is still alive and it works (tests are running inside). There must be a thing to track when a namespace complete its work.